# How to return the error cause from spring-boot based jms listener so that it is available on DLQ message

Tags: spring-boot, error-handling, jms, spring-jms

I have a spring-boot 2.6 based JMS listener that process messages dropped in an ActiveMQ queue.

When an error happened during processing, an uncaught exception is raised which lead to the message being retried a few times (depending on the maximumRedeliveries setting), until the limit is exceeded and the message is parked in the dead letter queue (DLQ).

That part works fine, and the support team can investigate messages in error, and even retry them once the cause of the issue has been fixed.

But it would be easier to investigate if the message in the DLQ could have some information about the raised error.

So far, when seeing the messages in the DLQ from the ActiveMQ broker UI, I can't help to notice on top of the body/payload and the headers, a property called dlqDeliveryFailureCause containing information about the redelivery limit being exceeded, without the root cause of why it was rejected on the last attempt.

So, I was wondering, is there any way on the listener side (the side raising the exception) that can be done to pass the error cause to the message parked in DLQ, either in a new property, by expanding the existing dlqDeliveryFailureCause message, or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to add a message property, you can't just let the message go by an uncaught exception. You would need to catch the exception, add your property and put the message to a dedicated backout queue.